# Removing duplicates from a file

Tags: java, text-parsing

I have a text file. I would like to make a set of 4 line and check if those 4 lines are unique. If they are unique copy it to another text file.

file.txt contains:

```
abc
12:12:11
john
12/25/2014
abc
12:12:11
doe
12/25/2014
abc
12:12:11
john
12/25/2014
```

The new txt file should only show.

```
abc
12:12:11
john
12/25/2014
abc
12:12:11
doe
12/25/2014

and delete
abc
12:12:11
john
12/25/2014
```

Is there any way to do this in Java? I cannot figure out how to use LinkedHashSet to get the result.

Comment: Those are sets of two lines you have here. Is it guaranteed that you always have an even number of lines in a file?

Comment: Also, which Java version is that?

Comment: Yes. The total number of lines in a will always be even. 1.6 java version

Comment: 1.6? Seriously? Hey, this is 2015; can't you at least use 1.7? If not, can you at least use an external library?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the dates are always matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since what you really have is sets of two lines, not one, the matter is a little more complicated than simply read the lines one by one and only trim duplicates.

Here is a solution using Java 7:

```
public static void eliminateDups(final String srcfile, final String dstfile)
    throws IOException
{
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    final Set<String> seen = new HashSet<>();
    final Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

    final Path src = Paths.get(srcfile);
    final Path dst = Paths.get(dstfile);

    try (
        final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(src, charset);
        final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(dst, charset,
            StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
    ) {
        String line1, line2;
        while ((line1 = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            line2 = reader.readLine();
            sb.setLength(0);
            if (!seen.add(sb.append(line1).append(line2).toString()))
                continue;
            writer.write(line1);
            writer.newLine();
            writer.write(line2);
            writer.newLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

For Java 6, I suggest you use Guava and its `Closer` to manage your I/O resources.

Comment: let me try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether the date will always guaranteed to be the same:

- if yes, then add all the lines into LinkedHashSet as a compound value,
- if no, then probably use `Map` to map from value to date.

Answer (score -1):

Just put each line into the Set, then write content of the set to a file. (yes the LinkedHashSet implemetnation to preserve the order)

Comment: Putting it into a Set may change the order of the lines.

Comment: He already knows to use LinkedHashSet so not to change the order.

Comment: If he already knows that he has to use a LinkedHashSet,  what's the point of your answer?